# How can I recursively get the sum of elements of an array in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion

Instead of using 
sum[1,2,3], which is a built-in library, how can I recursively add numbers in an array?
This is the code I think I should use but I get the following error:

```
sumThem (x:xs) = x + sumThem xs
```

This is how I call it from terminal window:

```
sumThem [1,2,3]
```

Here is the error

```
Exception: jan31.hs:21:1-25: Non-exhaustive patterns in function sumThem
```

Comment: what happens if you have an empty list? what is your base case?

Comment: Oh I didnt define a base case. Now it works! thank you!

Comment: You forgot to add a case for the empty list. I do not get why people always keep making exactly the same error.

Comment: That's right, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell non exhaustive patterns in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749675/haskell-non-exhaustive-patterns-in-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as-written is:

```
sumThem :: Num a => [a] -> a
sumThem (x:xs) = x + sumThem xs
```

This matches all non-empty lists (because they pattern-match on `(x:xs)`), but look what happens when we follow the recursion:

```
sumThem [1,2,3]
-> 1 + sumThem [2,3]
-> 1 + 2 + sumThem [3]
-> 1 + 2 + 3 + sumThem []
```

Uh oh, now Haskell doesn't know what to do. You haven't defined a *base case* for your recursive function, and so it doesn't know when to end. In this case that is realized by failing to pattern match against an empty list. To write the base case, just imagine a reasonable answer to the question "What's the sum of an empty set of numbers?"

```
sumThem :: Num a => [a] -> a
sumThem (x:xs) = x + sumThem xs
sumThem []     = 0
```

Now your recursion looks like:

```
sumThem [1,2,3]
-> 1 + sumThem [2,3]
-> 1 + 2 + sumThem [3]
-> 1 + 2 + 3 + sumThem []
-> 1 + 2 + 3 + 0
=  6
```